# Write a logarithmic iterative algorithm

Tags: algorithm, discrete-mathematics

Write a logarithmic iterative algorithm for calculating  using successive multiplication, where n is a perfect power of 3. Help Please!

Comment: Help with what? What did you try? Calculating what?

Comment: sorry calculating x^n

Comment: If this is discrete mathematics, wouldn't this question be better suited on either [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) or [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: im sorry im still new here thank you for your advice ill post there.

Comment: You still need to form a better question. Please explain with a bit more words what you want help with. Also, "someone gave me this question, can you answer it for me" doesn't really fly on any of the stackexchange sites, you need to give us something to work with so we can help *you* help *yourself*.

Comment: public static int power(int x, int n)
{
    int total = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) // i can be declared here directly
    {   
        total = (x * total);
    }
    return total; // total remains 1 if n = 0   
}

Comment: you need update(edit) your question with code snippet and do not write it in comment as it is not readable